# How to do UX research whiteboard challenge during an interview?

Tags: user-research, ux-field, interview

I'm going to a final round of interview for a UX Researcher position. An important part of the onsite interview is a research challenge: given a specific topic, write a research proposal, and do a presentation in 3 hours. Can you provide me with some advice on how to best prepare for this kind of exercise and what are the things I need to pay close attention to during the interview?
Thanks a lot! Appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> An important part of the onsite interview is a research challenge: given a specific topic, write a research proposal, and do a presentation in 3 hours.

I think you've answered your own question in a way. It sounds as though you know what's coming, so you can prepare by rehearsing this same exercise with some arbitrary topics. Pick a topic, write a proposal. Are they expecting you to pitch the research or also present some hypothetical findings? Think about it both ways, in case it comes up as a curveball. If you rehearse the exercise, you'll be able to do it vs. ponder what to do on the day of the interview.

3 hours seems like a long exercise for anything that isn't later rounds, by the way, so invest an appropriate amount of preparation time.